# Scriptable Object not showing up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wonder why my ScriptableObject isn't showing up?
I am using unity version `2022.3.11f1` with Visual Studio Code.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Jancok", menuName = "percobaan/Jancok")]
public class Percobaan : ScriptableObject

{
    public string prefabName;

    public int numberOfPrefabsToCreate;
    public Vector3[] spawnPoints;
}
```

[image]

If there are any deficiencies in the installation or other things, let me know

Comment: its not off the bottom?

Comment: There is a little pointer pointing upwards in the context menu ... can you click on that?

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for answering my question... it turns out this is a bug in my Unity where I just need to reopen it